# Add referer to .Navigate, skybound geckofx browser

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer, xulrunner, geckofx

I was trying to add a referrer to a .Navigate commmand.

my code is;

```
geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com.tr/");
```

I'm using Visual Studio, c#, windows forms project and I added xulrunner and skybound gecko .net component.
Is it possible? if it is, please explain using my code sample, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found out myself, its;

```
geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com.tr/", Skybound.Gecko.GeckoLoadFlags.BypassHistory, referrer, null, null);
```

And it requires a string inside the class;

```
public string referrer = "http://www.yourreferrer.com/";
```